# ROS 2: rqt vs rqt_graph

Tags: ros2

In ROS 2, what is the difference between the `rqt` and `rqt_graph` commands?  They both seem to bring up the `rqt visualizer`, which works great.  Is there actually a difference?  Does one simlink to the other?  I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rqt` is a generic visualizer which has a plugin interface. The `rqt` generic executable is provided by the [`rqt_gui` package](https://index.ros.org/p/rqt_gui).

[`rqt_graph`](https://index.ros.org/p/rqt_graph/) is a specific plugin for `rqt` that provides a convenience command line executable with the same name to launch the visualizer specifically configured with that plugin loaded.